# Alternate way to say "own company" & "family-owned company"

Tags: synonyms

I am applying for a new job; I currently work in my family-owned F&B firm. Now, in the job portal, there is a column where I have to mention my current company. I don't want to give the name of my firm as it is not well-known and also, it is not in the same domain as the job I am applying for.

I have currently put down "Own F&B establishment" in the column. But the "own" part seems kind of odd to me. Is there any other word or phrase that I can use instead, which would indicate I am not just working there, but am a stakeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that you're *"currently **running** the **family business**"*.
This means that you're a stakeholder in that business and that you work there.

**Family business** — [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/family-business.html)

> Company owned by one or more family members. In some cases, a family business may be owned by more than one family.

**Run** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/run)

> *verb* 6. (with object) Be in charge of; manage
>
> *"Andrea runs her own catering business"*
> *(as adjective, in combination -run)* *"an attractive family-run hotel"*

Answer (score 1):

Currently working in Closed corporation or Private corporation/company also works. [see here](https://www.interglot.com/dictionary/en/en/translate/family%20business)